# Envelope Distort a Group Objects in Illustator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, layers, distort

I have a collection of objects inside a layer. Looks something like this:
[image]

Now I need to make Envelope Distortions to the entire layer, so that it looks realistic on all object.
But the problem is on layer selection I can't select anything in the *Envelope Distort* submenu (apart from the envelope distort options).

Is there any way to make this work without having to flatten the whole layer (or flatten in a way that colors would still be editable by dtp people)

I'm fairly new to this software so please have patience with me :P

**EDIT**: The layer does not contain a raster image. There are only a vector path and a text layer

Comment: Is one of your objects a raster image? If so, then that explains it.

Comment: @BillyKerr it does not

Comment: This question can't be answered if you won't willingly provide more information when people ask you to clarify. So, I'm voting to close it as too broad.

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm sorry. Updated the question

Comment: I can't replicate the problem with a group containing a text layer and two paths, so something else has to be wrong.

Comment: Question to be deleted. I was selecting the layers wrong. Damn photoshop habits

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the questioner admits there's no actual problem, he had himself made a mistake which is now rectified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out and it turns out that

## I'm a moron

Was selecting layer by clicking on it, and not on the little roundy boi text to the layer name.

Sorry to waste all of y'all time

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of as to why Envelope Distort would *not* be possible would be a **linked** raster image.

In order to Envelope Distort raster images, they **must** be *embedded*, not linked.

Merely highlight the image in the `Links` Panel (Window > links) and then choose `Embed Image` from the panel fly out menu.

You should then be able to apply an envelope distortion.

Comment: No Sir. The layer only contains a text and one path.

Comment: Then I have no clue why Envelope Distort would fail to work. I can't replicate any problem with merely text and a path.

Answer (score 0):

Before you distort the objects, group them.

This will make a distorted group with all inner objects selectable and editable.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Grouping isn't really required. In fact, the envelope kind of acts like a pseudo-group..

Comment: He is talking about sublayer, @Scott